# How can I add auto-increment Id in these tables because the "identify" don't work?

Tags: sql

```
Create database Gestion_Etudiant

use Gestion_Etudiant
Create table Etudiant(
      idE int primary key identify,
      Nom varchar(50),
      Prenom varchar(50),
      Moyenne float       
)

Create Table Module(
     idM int primary key identify,
     Libelle varchar(50),
     Coefficient int
)
```

My question is:
How can I add auto-increment Id in these tables because the "identify" don't work??

Comment: I use SQL Managment Server 2008 ''

Comment: What does "don't work" mean, exactly?

Comment: The spelling is different. Should be [`identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), not `identify`.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'identify' this is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create database Gestion_Etudiant

use Gestion_Etudiant
Create table Etudiant(
      idE int primary key identify,
      Nom varchar(50),
      Prenom varchar(50),
      Moyenne float       
)

Create Table Module(
     idM int primary key identify,
     Libelle varchar(50),
     Coefficient int
)
```

The problem is here: idE int primary key identify,

In fact you're naming the primary key as `identify`

Use the correct syntax:

```
FIELD_NAME IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Thanks verry much i get it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IDENTITY` (and not identify) to declare auto increment field, e.g.:

```
Create table Etudiant(
      idE int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
      Nom varchar(50),
      Prenom varchar(50),
      Moyenne float       
)
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb06a/1/0)**.